# Suggestions for a system similar to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, clone

I'm looking for a engine similar to Stack Overflow for asking questions and what not. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stack Overflow Clones?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones)

Answer (score 3):

if you have specific theme, you can always suggest the idea in http://area51.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a StackExchange 2.0 site once they become available.

Comment: I would love to use it. Where can I get it?